# Can we add single UDID of iOS Device in 2 different provisioning profile

Tags: ios, xcode, appium

Please pardon me with my limited knowledge on iOS. I have very recently moved to iOS app testing using Appium.

Let me explain my situation. We are thinking to get subscription from any mobile lab vendors like browserstack or mobile labs. They will provide actual real devices (after we connect to their portal)

know if i need to test my app on actual iOS device I need to have apple developer license and need to have provisioning profile which would have device UDID.

Now is it possible that single UDID can be listed in different provisioning profile for different accounts.

I am asking because one of the vendor told us that its Apple policy and since vendor's device is already registered in vendor's provisioning profile hence the same device can not be used in my company's provisioning profile.

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Comment: ive used my personal iphone on my own apple dev account, and the company i work for's apple dev account, so yes you can

Comment: I don't think there will be any issue if you add once single device Id in multiple provisioning profile or in different apple developer account

Answer (score 1):

Of course, you can add an UDID to as many provisioning profiles(PP) as you want.

If you still have issues that the device is not register, you should update your PP from developer.apple.com (Devices & Certificates section) and check the UDID as used for that PP.

If you still have issues delete from Xcode the PP and download it again.

Answer (score 0):

I done it and didn't get any problem nor any complain from Apple: I use the same set of test devices for different customers in the last 5 years...